# SQL Server Environment Settings, how to easily import to improve my daily workflow

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I use SQL Server daily as an analyst.  Daily I import my settings so that my ad hoc queries look better.  Is there a way to automate this or make it easier?

I currently click TOOLS, IMPORT AND EXPORT SETTINGS, IMPORT ENVIRONMENT SETTINGS, NO(IMPORT NEW SETTINGS),CLICK ON MY SETTINGS FILE(it's called MySettings.vssettings),FINISH,CLOSE.

[Image of Import Export Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKdoZ.png)

I want to change the "DEFAULT" to MySettings.vssettings, or some other simple way.

Thanks for any advice!

```
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio                      14.0.17177.0 
Microsoft Analysis Services Client Tools                    14.0.806.134 
Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC)                     6.1.7601.17514 
Microsoft MSXML                                             3.0 4.0 6.0 
Microsoft Internet Explorer                                 9.11.9600.19002 
Microsoft .NET Framework                                    4.0.30319.42000 
Operating System                                            6.1.7601
```

Comment: Sounds like something that could be researched over on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why are you having to do this daily? SSMS doesn't revert its settings every time you restart it.

Comment: It does not revert when I restart the program, but it does when I log off at night and back in in the morning.  It's a Citrix Access Gateway server desktop.  I still have not found a solution.